# Depth map for particle system using a texture map

Tags: dictionary, system, three.js, depth, particles

I'm trying to generate a depth map for a particle system, but if I render the particle system using MeshDepthMaterial, then every particle is only rendered as a single point for each vertex--not covering the entire area the texture mapped particle is displayed.

Do I need to use MeshDepthMaterial to generate a depth map, or are there other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now there is no way to get the MeshDepthMaterial to respect the size or texture of the ParticleSystem. However, it is not too hard to implement a custom ShaderMaterial that does that. First, you need a vertex shader and fragment shader.

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
  uniform float size;
  void main() {
    gl_PointSize = size;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position , 1.0 ); 
  }
</script>

<script type = "x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
  uniform sampler2D map;
  uniform float near;
  uniform float far;

  void main() {
    float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;
    float depthColor = 1.0 - smoothstep( near, far, depth );

    vec4 texColor = texture2D( map, vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y ) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3(depthColor), texColor.a);
  }
</script>
```

The vertex shader is totally standard, the fragment shader takes the texture (`sampler2D map`), but instead of using it for color values it just uses the alpha level `texColor.a`. For the rgb, a grayscale value based on the depth is used, [just like the MeshDepthMaterial](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLShaders.js#L1915-L1917). Now to use this shader you just need to grab the html and create a THREE.ShaderMaterial like so:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms : {
      size : { type: 'f', value : 20.0 },
      near : { type: 'f', value : camera.near },
      far  : { type: 'f', value : camera.far },
      map  : { type: "t", value : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( url ) }
    },
    attributes : {},
    vertexShader: vertShader,
    fragmentShader: fragShader,
    transparent: true
  });
```

Here you have provided the shader with all the info it needs: the camera's near/far range, the size of the particle and the texture it needs to map.

You can see a [jsFiddle demo of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fbcrs/3/).

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Great response. I actually didn't even need to generate a depth map, once I figured that the depth info used in the shader is available in the fragment shader (gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w) I could do the whole effect in a single pass.